# Why does Julia use the word "Sarcasm" to Security?

Tags: dialogue, valentines-day

In *Valentine's Day (2010)*, why does Julia use the word "Sarcasm" to Security ?

> Julia: Yeah. Guys love surprises.
>
> Julia: Is that **sarcasm**?
>
> Lady Security: I surprised my husband once. Now he's my ex-husband.

Comment: Are you sure the first line was said by Julia?

Answer (score 3):

[Sarcasm](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm) is when someone says something, but means something else. They mean either the opposite of what they said, or that they disagree with what they just said.

The lady security officer once tried to give her husband a surprise. After that, her husband left her which proves that guys don't like surprises.

That's why Julia said if she was using sarcasm here by telling that guys love surprises.

Comment: I think the subtext is the security officer inadvertently found out that her husband was cheating on her. That would be why the surprise caused the divorce.